# Cannot place two right docked panels one above other, is there any alternative

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

In my windows application, I have docked a panel to the right which has a group box and cancel & print buttons. I have another panel with a button and  groupbox and on button click, group box location is changed to make it a custom slider which has to be placed above this panel. I couldn't place the slider panel inside this right docked panel, because width differs.

I could place the slider panel without docking above this right docked panel. 
But when window resizes,all docked panels are resized accordingly except this slider panel.

Designer code for right docked panel.

```
this._pnlBasicPanelRight.Controls.Add(this._pnlBottomButtons);
this._pnlBasicPanelRight.Controls.Add(this._tgbxLocation);
this._pnlBasicPanelRight.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
this._pnlBasicPanelRight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1105, 0);
this._pnlBasicPanelRight.Name = "_pnlBasicPanelRight";
this._pnlBasicPanelRight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(167, 693);               
this._pnlBasicPanelRight.TabIndex = 44;
```

designer code for slider panel

```
this._pnlDataGrid.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
this._pnlDataGrid.Controls.Add(this._tgrpLimitValues,1,0);            
this._pnlDataGrid.Controls.Add(this._btnRightBottomPanelVisibility,0,0);
this._pnlDataGrid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(483, 370);
this._pnlDataGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1310, 159);              
this._pnlDataGrid.Name = "_pnlDataGrid";            
this._pnlDataGrid.TabIndex = 44;
```

[This is how i need my right panel to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrXlO.png)

Comment: The layout questions are hard to answer without complete [mcve] or pictures. Can you visualize the problem? Ideally as an animated gif (you can use tool like [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/))

Comment: How putting the two right-docked panels into another containing panel that contains just them, and then dock that containing panel as required?

Comment: @Sinatr I have added the image of how i need my screen to look like. Kindly refer. Thanks!

Comment: just put a panel on the form docked right, and on that panel put these 2 panels, one docked to top and the other docked as fill

Comment: You have the TableLayoutPanel control for this kind of layouts (the control's name gives it away). It also allows the dynamic, proportional, resize of its child controls.

Comment: @GuidoG But these two panels are of different widths. If I place them inside a panel, I have to give that panel the width of largest panel. But as you can see in my image, I want the panels to only take up the space required  by each of them.

Comment: I dont think that any form layout manager can do that for you, my guess is you need to write the positions and sizes of the panels yourself in code

Comment: @GuidoG I have docked one panel to right and placed other panel by giving locations wihtout docking. When i resize, docked panel alone is resizing, the undocked slider panel is not getting resized. Do you have any suggestion as to how I can handle this

Comment: you need to write sizing code in the Resize event of the form, and do the sizing of your panels yourself

Comment: @GuidoG thank you so much! I'll try that solution.

Answer (score 2):

Docking something sticks it to the right of its container and occupies the full height. You can't have two panels fighting for occupation of the full height and they don't know about each other so they won't intrinsically play nicely and divide up the space (there is no mechanism to apportion space)

You'll need to use a device that knows how to have two things taking up a height and can apportion space, such as a SplitContainer with a horizontal divide mode. Dock the splitcontainer to the right and put your two panels inside it, one on either side of the splitter

Comment: Thank @Caius Jard. I tried with split container in  horizontal divide mode. I was able to set panel1 and panel2's height. But Is there a way to set their width too? Panel1's width should be 167 and panel2's width as 480.

Comment: I have included the image of how my panel should look. Kindly help me with how I could achieve it using split container.

Comment: If you don't dock the panels inside the splitcontainer then you can set their width to whatever you like. As soon as you dock a panel it hands control of the sizing over to the parent container in at least one dimension, possibly even two dimensions (dock:fill). Example if you dock left you can control the width but not the height, if you dock top you can control the height but not the width. You probably want to dock right your panels inside the splitter so they stick to the right edge and too/bottom of the split pane  but you can still give them a width

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture you've posted I would forget docking (dock:none) and I would instead position the panels as you have done in your image and then set the anchor properties:

- top right panel: anchor top + right
- bottom right panel: anchor top + right + bottom

Anchor means "keep the same distance between the chosen edge and the same edge of the enclosing container"

This means your top right panel will move left and right when the window is resized bigger but it will not move down or grow larger. The bottom right panel will also move left and right, will not move up and down, but it will grow vertically as the window grows

If instead you want the bottom right panel to be a fixed size and the top panel to grow vertically:

- top right panel: anchor top + right + bottom
- bottom right panel: anchor bottom + right

This will make the bottom right panel a fixed size and glued into the bottom right of the window (moves up down left right, doesn't grow) and the top right panel will move left and right, won't grow horizontally but will grow and shrink vertically as the window height changes